# SQL Server : get max of the column2 and column3 value must be 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an output of some part of my stored proedure like this:

```
col1      col2  col3 col4
--------------------------
2016-05-05  1    2      2
2016-05-05  1    3     32
2016-05-12  2    1     11
2016-05-12  3    1     31
```

Now I need to get result based on this condition

```
col2 = 1 and col3 = max or col3 = 1 
and col2 = max
```

The final result should be

```
col1      col2  col3 col4
-------------------------
2016-05-05  1    3     32
2016-05-12  3    1     31
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats the most efficient way , but you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.col1 ORDER BY t.col3 DESC) as rnk,
    WHERE t.col2 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.col1 ORDER BY t.col2 DESC) as rnk,
    WHERE t.col3 = 1) tt
WHERE rnk = 1
```

This will give you all the records with

```
(col2=1 and col3=max) or (col3=1 and col2=max)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  Your data has no ambiguities, such as duplicate maximuma in `col4` or "1" values in both `col2` and `col3`.

The following is a direct translation of the logic in your question:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col4 = (select max(t2.col4)
                from t t2
                where t2.col1 = t.col1 and (t2.col2 = 1 or t2.col3 = 1)
               );
```

Comment: He doesn't care about `col4` ,`2=1 +max(3)` or `3=1 + max(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note if there are more than 1 same `max` value, then you need all of those in output. And it will work for all scenarios, even when `col1` is not in sync with `col2` and `col3`.

I am first finding highest values of `col2` and `col3` and assigning them value as `1`. Then in outer query, I am using your join condition. Demo created for Postgres DB as SQLServer wasn't available.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/04da9/1)**</kbd>

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
from 
(
    select t.*,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col3 DESC) as col3_max,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2 DESC) as col2_max
    from your_table t
) t1
where 
(col2=1 and col3_max=1)
OR
(col3=1 and col2_max=1)
```

Comment: If records with `col2 <> 1 and col3 <> 1` exists, that won't work.

Comment: If `col2 <> 1 and/or col3 <> 1 ` exists, it would not satisfy the `where` clause and would be skipped. Am I missing something?

Comment: The ranks won't necessarly be correct, rank `1` doesn't have to be with `col3` = 1 .

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY iif(col2 = 1, col3, col2) DESC) as r
    FROM tbl) t
WHERE r = 1
```